# Replace the first word in a string

Tags: python-3.x, string, indexing, replace, split

I am trying to replace the first word in a string, though it is not working. Any help?

```
s = 'No word in this sentence is                 
capitalised.'

replacement = 'All'
s.split()
s.replace(s,replacement,0)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative way to achieve the desired result:

```
s = 'No word in this sentence is capitalised.'

replacement = 'All'
s = s.split()
s[0] = replacement
print(' '.join(s))
```

- Split your sentence based on space.
- Store the string as a list.
- Replace the first word. The advantage here is that you can replace any word you want based on its index. `s[1] = replacement`, `s[2] = replacement`, etc.
- Join back the elements of the list as a single string.

Answer (score 2):

```py
s = 'No word in this sentence is capitalised.'
replacement = 'All'
s = s.replace(s[:s.index(' ')], replacement, 1)
print(s)
```

Comment: This kinda works for me, as python will assume every single character as an element, therefore each char will have its own index, if I could use the whitespace to say when it ends.

Comment: def rep1stW(x): ###
    replacement = 'All' ###
    s.split() ###
    x = x.replace(x[:3], replacement, 1)

Answer (score 1):

`s.replace()` takes 3 arguments (which you can also find out by running `help(s.replace)` yourself):

- `old` - the value you want to replace **inside** `s`
- `new` - the value to replace `old` with
- `count` - how many times to do the replace

So, you need to do:

```
>>> s.replace("No",replacement,1)
'All word in this sentence is capitalised.'
```

Comment: dijksterhuis I would like to use specific index to do that. I do grasp the concept I am just trying to dig a bit deeper to truly understand python and this community has been great so far.